# How can i show the connectors for my 3d funnel?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIys4.png) I am facing an overlap problem regarding my 3d funnel using highcharts. I have also attached an image showing the problem. hope it might help you to debug

I've already tried the api reference as per the highcharts documantation

```
function sales_funnel(key_val, response) {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('funnel_container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel3d',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 10,
                depth: 50,
                viewDistance: 50
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Sales Funnel'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            funnel3d: {
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    connectorAllowed: true,
                    connectorNeighbourDistance: 30
                },
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name} ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                },
                neckWidth: '30%',
                neckHeight: '25%',
                width: '80%',
                height: '80%'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: response[1],
            data: key_val
        }]
    });
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: I think its a bug you should open an issue [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues).

Comment: okay... thanks for the help

Comment: Unfortunately, connectors are not supported in funnel 3d yet. You can set `series.dataLabels.allowOverlap = false` to prevent labels overlapping.

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work either... so i switched to the option of connectors

Comment: Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nvdcg872/

Comment: thanks but if you see clearly downloads 1 is missing between website visits and downloads 2

Comment: Yes, it is missing because it is overlapping the next label.